# Move record from Oracle array to Cobol occurs

Tags: oracle, cobol, embedded-sql, procobol

How can I move a record from oracle to a Cobol array?
When I move a single field, everything works as expected.
When I try to move a record in an Oracle VARRAY I cannot 
get it to work. The PRO*COBOL precompiler gives the following error message:

```
Error at line 137, column 12 in file ESF3.ordbso07.PCO
            EXEC SQL EXECUTE      
 ...........1
 PCB-S-00576, PLS-382: expression is of wrong type
 Error at line 137, column 12 in file ESF3.ordbso07.PCO
            EXEC SQL EXECUTE      
 ...........1
 PCB-S-00576, PLS-0: Statement ignored
```

Oracle types:

```
TYPE QDELSSRD_arr IS VARRAY(30) OF QDELSSRD_typ;

TYPE SODLSSRD_typ IS RECORD ( -- DBSO07 SOK
    QDELSSRD             QDELSSRD_arr -- 30 x QDELSSRD_typ

OC is SODLSSRD_typ;
TYPE QDELSSRD_typ IS RECORD (
    ENAMN                arbetssokande.efternamn%type, -- VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
    FNAMN                arbetssokande.fornamn%type, -- VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
);
```

Snippet of COBOL ESQL anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
FOR LV IN 1..:RC-ZHITS
LOOP
    :QDELSSRD(LV) :=  OC.QDELSSRD(LV);
 END LOOP;
```

COBOL variable declaration:

```
     15     QSODLSSRD.
            18     QDELSSRD                      OCCURS 30.
                   21     ENAMN                         PIC X(030).
                   21     FNAMN                         PIC X(020).
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use VARYING... For example:

```
18     QDELSSRD                      VARYING OCCURS 20 TIMES. 
 21     ENAMN                         PIC X(030).    
 21     FNAMN                         PIC X(020).
```

http://www.pitt.edu/~hoffman/oradoc/server.804/a58232/ch04.htm